# Installation of Kaldi, error on compiling gst-kaldi-nnet2-online on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, kaldi

What i try to do is to install [silvius-backend](https://github.com/dwks/silvius-backend) on my ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine, but unfortunately it is not working without the proper compile of both of kaldi and [gst-kaldi-nnet2-online](https://github.com/alumae/gst-kaldi-nnet2-online) .

I have compiled **kaldi** successfully but I am experiencing a error when i try to compile **gst-kaldi-nnet2-online**.

I follow these [instructions](https://github.com/dwks/silvius-backend/blob/master/INSTALL).

Here is what i do:

1. I am using **Ubuntu 16.04.**
2. I have compiled **kaldi** successfully with the following commands:

   in `kaldi/tools` -->  `sudo make CXX=g++-5`

   in `kaldi/src` --> `sudo CXX=g++-5 ./configure --shared`, `sudo make clean CXX=g++-5` ,`sudo make depend CXX=g++-5` ,`sudo make CXX=g++-5`
3. I tried to do `sudo make depend` from `~/gst-kaldi-nnet2-online/src` and i got an error like this:

> Makefile:6: * Cannot find Kaldi's makefile /home/tanel/tools/kaldi-    trunk/src/kaldi.mk. Specify Kaldi's root directory using KALDI_ROOT when issuing make, e.g.: KALDI_ROOT=/home/tanel/tools/kaldi-trunk make .  Stop.

4. So In [this path](https://github.com/alumae/gst-kaldi-nnet2-online/blob/master/src/Makefile#L3) i have changed the path to: "KALDI_ROOT=~/kaldi"

   And now i am getting an error like this :

> g++-5 -M -std=c++11 -I.. -I/home/silvius/kaldi/tools/openfst/include -pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Winit-self -DKALDI_DOUBLEPRECISION=0 -DHAVE_EXECINFO_H=1 -DHAVE_CXXABI_H -DHAVE_ATLAS -I/home/silvius/kaldi/tools/ATLAS_headers/include -msse -msse2 -pthread -g  -fPIC -I~/kaldi/src *.cc > .depend.mk
>   In file included from gst-audio-source.cc:22:0:
>   ./gst-audio-source.h:23:33: fatal error: matrix/kaldi-vector.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   In file included from ./gstkaldinnet2onlinedecoder.h:26:0,
>                    from gstkaldinnet2onlinedecoder.cc:49:
>   ././simple-options-gst.h:25:33: fatal error: util/simple-options.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   In file included from simple-options-gst.cc:20:0:
>   ./simple-options-gst.h:25:33: fatal error: util/simple-options.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   Makefile:76: recipe for target 'depend' failed
>   make: [depend] Error 1 (ignored)

You can see the error on a picture aswell on [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV4ZX.png)

PS: the path to my Folders is that ones:

```
 `~/kaldi` for kaldi's folder , and

 `~/gst-kaldi-nnet2-online` for the gst-kaldi-nnet2-online. 

 (i cloned them from github inside `~/` in separated folders)
```

I dont know what to do next or what is the problem. I've been looking for a solution since days on the internet but i found nothing. Can someone help me?

Comment: `~` symbol does not work in Makefiles, only in shell. You need to use full path `KALDI_ROOT=/home/silvius/kaldi`

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev thanks for the info. I passed this error but now i get this

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkaldi-thread`
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkaldi-thread`
`collect2: error: ls returned 1 exit status`
`make: *** [libgstkaldionline2.so] Error 1`

Comment: Kaldi-thread library was removed from Kaldi. You can remove it from makefile too. Overall it is better to check out proper branch of kaldi otherwise you will have to fix several things in the codebase.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev what do you mean by "branch" of kaldi? sorry i am new to these enviroments and i am trying to understand.

Comment: I believe the gst code should work with brach "5.1" https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/5.1, master has API incompatibility